# Move camera between canvases in UI menu

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a scene for a dynamic menu, where I'm trying to make the camera move between the canvases (menu entities in this case) when a button is pressed. How can I make it move to another canvas space using four canvas corners so the camera's field of view can attach itself to these four corners. P.S. I'me pretty new to Unity, don't be too judgy. 
Something like this plan.

[Menu Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLpt1.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not move canvas? camera focus centered to 0,0,0 position for example and you move out of camera fov the canvas you like

Comment: @joreldraw It's not really doable in my case, since I plan to make a menu like a level (room) and to move arond to certain parts of the room depending on the menu

Comment: I think if you provide image or clearer visualisation of what you tried to achieve, it be easier for others to help you.

Comment: @Tengku One sec

Answer (score 1):

As far I have understood, you can set the Canvas **Render Mode** to **World Space** from the inspector.
Then you can position the Canvas position as your wish.
Please see the attached images.[image]

[image]

Comment: you only have 1 camera to show that menu, why not just control the camera by rotating and moving it. if you going to have the menu like your `Menu Layout` you can just divide 360 by amount of surround room..and use the angle result to rotate the camera